# Visio automation / assigning window to drawing

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to add click events to shapes within a visio file.. I have the functionality to pick up the click events but i cant figure out how to assign the window control to the drawing window of the file.

my attempt..

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("visio.exe", "test.vdx")
    sourceWindow = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Window
    sourceWindow.Src = "Path"
```

I keep getting error, note if more details are needed il provide them promptly, note that path is the same as test.vdx?

this is the code, for taking in the window object..

```
  Public Class HandleMouseEvents

    Private Const shapesFoundPrompt As String = _
        "Shapes at the click location:"
    Private Const noShapesFoundPrompt As String = _
        "No shapes at the click location."

    Private clickedWindow As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Window

    '// <summary>This constructor initiates handling of the MouseUp event
    '// by storing a reference to the window and assigning the event
    '// handling procedure this class defines as a delegate  
    '// to the window's MouseUp event.</summary>
    <CLSCompliant(False)> _
    Public Sub New(ByVal subjectWindow As  _
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Window)

        Try

            '// Add the MouseUp handler to the window.  When the event is
            '// raised mouseUp_EventHandler will be called.
            clickedWindow = subjectWindow
            AddHandler clickedWindow.MouseUp, _
                AddressOf mouseUp_EventHandler

        Catch errorThrown As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
            Debug.WriteLine(errorThrown.Message)
        End Try
```

I try to get the window to pass to the above code  and create the vdx document within a button click event on a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VBA**

You must have a reference to the Visio application. In order to do that you must either get an already open Visio instance or create a new one

```
Dim visio as Object, doc as Object

On Error Resume Next

' Try to get existing Visio instance
Set visio = GetObject(, "Visio.Application")
If visio Is Nothing Then   ' Visio is not open
    ' Open Visio
    Set visio = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
    If visio Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot open Visio!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set doc = visio.Documents.Open("C:\MyVisioDocsPath\test.vdx")
visio.Visible = True
```

Note that I used late binding here, which means that I have no reference set to Visio. The advantage is that your code will work with any version of Visio; however, you will not enjoy intellisense for Visio objects.

You can also set a reference to Visio and then use concrete types like `Visio.Application` and `Visio.Document`, which gives you intellisense on Visio objects.

---

UPDATE: **VB.NET**

Set a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio in your project and import the namespace like this

```
Imports Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio
```

Now, you can simply open a document like this

```
Dim visio As New Visio.Application
Dim doc As Visio.Document

doc = visio.Documents.Open("C:\MyVisioDocsPath\test.vdx")
AddHandler visio.ActiveWindow.MouseUp, AddressOf Window_MouseUp
```

The handler looks like this

```
Private Sub Window_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal KeyButtonState As Integer, _
                ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByRef CancelDefault As Boolean)
    Console.WriteLine("x = {0},  y = {1}", x, y)
End Sub
```

Or you can define a member variable (in the class or module, not local to a method) like this

```
Dim WithEvents window As Visio.Window
```

Then you can simply select the `window` variable from the drop-down-list on the upper left of the code editor and an event from the upper right drop-down-list to generate a handler automatically (and you can drop the line with `AddHandler`). After opening the document you would assign the active window to the variable like this

```
window = visio.ActiveWindow
```

Comment: edited the above code, there might have been a bit of confusion here, also "set" keyword there is that used in vb.net?

Comment: Sorry, I recently answered a VBA question and mixed up the two. I added a VB.NET example.

Comment: ah ok i see, if to assign the drawing to the window then i could say test = handlemouseevent(doc) pass doc to it?

Comment: I updated the example and explain two ways of adding event handlers.

Comment: Thank you so much this was great help, I have it recognizing the shape being clicked.. i just need to get the text from the shapes and compare them :) thanks again

Comment: is there anyway using a method to get the clicked shapes that i can find the shapes under the specified pointer? I want to create a custom mouse over as it where, i know i can use spatial search but i don't know how to get the current pointer location

Comment: You should accept this answer and post a new question. This is an old question and the chance that someone answers the new question is much greater than getting a new answer to this old question.